# what is bool(), int(), and double() in c++/c++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

what is `bool()`, `int()`, and `double()` in c++/c++11? Are they `true`, `0` and `0.0` in c++ or c++11 standard?

Comment: Actually it is `false`, `0` and `0.0` respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`T()` ia a value-initialized prvalue of type `T` since C++03 when value-initialization was introduced.

It is `false` for `bool`, `0` for arithmetic and `nullptr` for pointer-types.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting the C++11 FD, [expr.type.conv]/2:

> The expression `T()`, where `T` is a *simple-type-specifier* or
>   *typename-specifier* for a non-array complete object type or the
>   (possibly cv-qualified) `void` type, creates a prvalue of the specified
>   type, **whose value is that produced by value-initializing (8.5) an
>   object of type `T`**; no initialization is done for the `void()` case.

And value-initialization implies zero-initialization for scalars.

Comment: That quote again from you ... +1.

Comment: How is your average Joe supposed to use a language whose specs look like a draft law on sheep breeding programmes, I wonder...

Comment: Just curious but are you really 17? How did you get so good?